# How do I code this google sheets IFS function into app script code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

*This line of code was imported into app script via google sheets macro record, where it was written in a google sheet as a formula. How do I convert this into pure app script, which executes the IFS and then inserts the output into the corresponding cells?*

What I'm trying to learn is, basically, how I code
if cell A1 = "var 1", B1 = "var 2", and if A1 = "var 7", B1 = "var 8".

In other words, how to set a variable in one cell to cause a variable to be set in another.

````
sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IFS(R[0]C[1]="Owner Withdrawal","Dividends",R[0]C[1]="Supplies","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Services","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Cash", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Equipment", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Payable", "Liabilities", R[0]C[1]="Owner Equity", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Retained Earnings", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Revenue","Revenue", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Receivable", "Revenue")');```
````

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: No, this is not.

Comment: Does your formula ork as intended if you set it inot the cell without Apps Script?

Comment: It does work as intend, yes. It works via the app script, too. What I'm tying to solve here is getting away from having these long IFS formulas in the cells my spreadsheets, and instead having them contained within the app script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script has no facilities to evaluate or "run" spreadsheet formulas. To make it work without using formulas, you have to implement identical logic in pure JavaScript, perhaps like this:

```
const targetCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
const sourceCell = targetCell.offset(0, 1);
const value = sourceCell.getValue();
let result;
switch (value) {
  case 'Owner Withdrawal':
    result = 'Dividends';
    break;
  case 'Supplies':
    result = 'Expenses';
    break;
  // ...
  default:
    result = NaN;
}
targetCell.setValue(result);
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is just what I was looking for. I appreciate it.